# Cartography on iOS: CenterX constraint not honored when animating

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, cartography

I'm trying to animate a UILabel using [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography)
and using this code:

```
    let group = ConstraintGroup()

    constrain(alertLabel, replace: group) { alertLabel in
        alertLabel.centerX  == alertLabel.superview!.centerX
        alertLabel.width == alertLabel.superview!.width * Constants.alertLabelWidthMultiplier
        alertLabel.bottom == alertLabel.superview!.top + 0
    }

    constrain(alertLabel, replace: group) { alertLabel in
        alertLabel.centerX  == alertLabel.superview!.centerX
        alertLabel.width == alertLabel.superview!.width * Constants.alertLabelWidthMultiplier
        alertLabel.bottom == alertLabel.superview!.top + 60
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: alertLabel.layoutIfNeeded)
```

[image]

I want my UILabel to be centered in the beginning and end of the animation.
However, it seems to start on the top left corner of the superview instead.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with this line:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: alertLabel.layoutIfNeeded)
```

It should be:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: alertLabel.superview!.layoutIfNeeded)
```

The centerX relational NSLayoutConstraint is on the superview - thus it's the superview that needs layoutIfNeeded called upon.